# Pinging JDBC Connection Pool in Glassfish Hangs Indefinitely

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, glassfish

I am really stuck with why my GlassFish connection pool does not ping successfully. When I try a long-running process alert comes up which I have to remove in order to access options again in the admin console.

Things to note:

- I can ping the connection with the same settings locally using the same driver (I am trying to connect on a Dev machine).
- I have another SQL Server database which is pingable from the development Glassfish installation I am trying to create the new connection on (the database is a SQL Server database).
- I cannot see any log output of any worth, the only thing it seems to print out is "Interrupting idle Thread" messages.

Any suggestions on what to try next? Does anyone know if I could increase the logging detail would this likely give me more information?

Thanks,
Matt.

Answer (score 0):

Copy connection jar files to 'domains\domain1\lib\ext' folder. Then restart your glassfish.

Comment: Thanks for response but this made no difference.

Comment: Sorry this is not possible.